# Using Tika to search files with Solr and Drupal

Tags: drupal, solr, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika with Solr to search nodes with attachments (zips, pdfs, etc), in the DB we have indexed nodes with files. looks as if it all is configured correct with Solr (Tika too) but the results are empty. I am only getting results for one PDF file that I created to test, It contain one word ‘MyTestNew’.autocomplete shows it but not after submit.

search works by title but not by file contents. http://screencast.com/t/lhSvs0iJS

We think maybe it’s a problem in the code. Maybe module_invoke_all() for the apache search integrated module. But not sure for now.’